# How do i acces a variable containing $_POST from another page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have one html page with on top php form validation to check if the fields are empty,  after that a html form and after that some html that displays a error message if fields are not filled in. The top of the form looks like:

```
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
```

In the PHP that is on top of the page, I check to see if the input fields are empty.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==='POST')
{

          if($_POST["field1"]==""){
                    $errormessage = "field1 is not empty";

           }elseif($_POST["field2"]==""){
                 $errormessage = "field1 is not empty";
            }else{
            // if the fields are both filled in i want to send the form 
            //variables to mailing.php where are the variables are mailed

}
```

This is the html for the errorcode that is part of my page:

If both fields are filled I want to send the POST data to `mailing.php` where I can format the variables into a html email.

Because i have a lot of variables I want  to send the whole $_POST variable to mailing.php using:

```
header('location:mailing.php?post='.$_POST);
```

But how do i acces a varable inside the $_POST in mail.php?
This did not work:

```
$inputfield = $_GET["post"]["field1"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is a bad design.*** You should include `mailing.php` and write a logic to access `$_POST` depending on some conditions. However if you still wish to forward the request, you can achieve it using [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/mailing.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The including was the best option!